# Row-level locking in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql

What is the mechanism to achieve Row-level locking in Cassandra ? What I want to do is to allow only one process to modify a given row at any given time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra does not provide locking. It does provide lightweight transactions, which can replace locking in some cases. Also note that operations on a single row are atomic, so locking a row is not necessarily to ensure a read or write of a row provides consistent field values for that row.

Cassandra does not provide locking because of a fundamental constraint on all kinds of distributed data store: a distributed data store can not ensure consistency while also providing performance and availability, but it can provide two of those three properties. The design of Cassandra chooses not to provide consistency, so it can provide high performance and availability. Locking is about consistency. So Cassandra could not provide locking without sacrificing performance and/or availability. As that would go against the design goals of Cassandra, it is a good bet that Cassandra will *never* have locking functionality.

Do you *really* need locking? You might be surprised that it is not as often necessary as you might think, if you have an RDBMS background. If you do need it, you must choose a different data-store, which is designed to provide consistency at the cost of either performance or availability (or both).